How should I re-level my paver walkway?
The walkway to my house is made of bricks and these large stones that serve as steps.  One of the stone steps shifted so that when we walk down the walkway, it's a trip hazard.  I tried to youtube videos of repointing bricks but I couldn't find any situation like mine.
What tools do I need to fix this, and how do I fix it?  Is it a 1-man job or do I need to grab a friend, given the weight of these large stones?



This is not a "repointing bricks" situation.  It's a settlement or a tree root displacement situation—possibly both.  Can't tell without more pics, but the solution is the same.
You need to remove and reset the (granite?) step, and remove and reset all the bricks between it and the uphill step.  Construction here should basically be like a brick patio—from the bottom up: compacted subgrade, landscape fabric, 4-6" gravel layer, landscape fabric, leveling sand, brick.
I note there appears to be some displacement in the brick near the downhill step too.

I wouldn't move the stone steps unless they're substantially out of level. Just reset the brick to their heights.

Oh interesting. So you're proposing to keep the stone step in place and then take out the brick before the step to somehow reset it to the stone's height?  How many bricks do you think I'll have to take out, a few rows before the stone step?

do not move stones. remove all bricks, level ground, add sand to have bricks same level as stones.

@k_z sorry mate, just more clarifying questions since I've never done this. I remove all the bricks between the two stones; do I need to put down a landscape fabric? Also, do you happen to know how much sand I should buy? Do I need any gravel? And what's between the bricks, is it mortar?

@isherwood depends how out-of level the steps are.  It's hard to tell from the photo angle, but if that one next to the tree has a significantly different slope than the bricks above it (after being reset), it could be a hazard—you're walking on the bricks, then you step on a wet step that's steeper than the bricks, and whoops!

@David I gave you the order for the layers.  You typically want 3/4-1" of leveling sand.

One other thing to mention: since it's likely that the tree roots are a problem, you're going to want to trim those back so you don't have to do this all over again in the future.  I can't say what that will do for the tree's longevity—I'm not an arborist, nor do I play one on TV.
